# MongoDB check documents for first date that is missing or has has missing values

Tags: mongodb

I have documents with two fields: `date` and `key`, where `date` represents days in format `"YYYY-MM-DD"` for this year, starting at 2019-01-01.
It is possible that for some date there is no document **OR** that the document for this date has no values (=`null`) in the `key` field.
Is it possible to create **one** query that finds the first date in this year for which no document exists or whose `key` field has no values?
**First example:**

```
[
    {date: "2019-01-01", key: "value"},
    {date: "2019-01-02", key: "value"},
    {date: "2019-01-04", key: "value"}
]
```

should return `"2019-01-03"` since this date is missing in the documents.
**Second example:**

```
[
    {date: "2019-01-01", key: "value"},
    {date: "2019-01-02", key: "value"},
    {date: "2019-01-03", key: null},
    {date: "2019-01-04", key: "value"}
]
```

should return `"2019-01-03"` as well since this date has no value for the `key` field.

When using some kind of sorting or min aggregation on the `date` field, the date would not be correct in the first example. I only found a way to loop over the days and check if there is a document for this `date` and that has a non-null value for the `key` field. However this solution is a query for each day.

Answer (score 0):

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $sort:{
            "date":-1
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":null,
            "dates":{
                $push:"$$ROOT"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "info":{
                $reduce:{
                    "input":"$dates",
                    "initialValue":{
                        "previousDate":"9999-01-01",
                        "missing":"",
                        "with_null_key":""
                    },
                    "in":{
                        "missing":{
                            $cond:[
                                {
                                    $gt:[
                                        {
                                            $subtract:[
                                                {
                                                    $toDate:"$$value.previousDate"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    $toDate:"$$this.date"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        86400000
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    $toString:{
                                        $toDate:{
                                            $add:[
                                                {
                                                    $toLong:{
                                                        $toDate:"$$this.date"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                86400000
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "$$value.missing"
                            ]
                        },
                        "with_null_key":{
                            $cond:[
                                {
                                    $eq:["$$this.key",null]
                                },
                                "$$this.date",
                                "$$value.with_null_key"
                            ]
                        },
                        "previousDate":"$$this.date"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "_id":0,
            "first_missing":"$info.missing",
            "first_with_null_key":"$info.with_null_key"
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

**Data set:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7bb4d6226855e3ea97001b"),
    "date" : "2019-01-01",
    "key" : "value"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7bb4d6226855e3ea97001c"),
    "date" : "2019-01-02",
    "key" : "value"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7bb4d6226855e3ea97001d"),
    "date" : "2019-01-04",
    "key" : "value"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d7bc2a7226855e3ea97001e"),
    "date" : "2019-01-05",
    "key" : null
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "first_missing" : "2019-01-03T00:00:00.000Z",
    "first_with_null_key" : "2019-01-05"
}
```

**Query Analysis:**

- The documents are searched in descending order of date
- All documents are pushed into an array called `dates`
- The [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) is performed on the `dates` array

  - If the difference of previous date and current date is greater than 86400000 (millisecond equivalent of 1 day) then the missing date would be current date + 1 day
  - If the key for the date is missing, then the date is saved in field `with_null_key`

Answer (score 0):

You can generate all dates for a year using [$range](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/index.html), [$dateFromParts](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromParts/index.html) and [$dateToString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/index.html) operators,
then [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) the collection for the missing documents:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        { $limit: 1 },
        { $project: {
            _id: 0,
            day: { $map: {
                input: { $filter: { 
                    input: { $map: {
                        input: { $range: [ 1, 367, 1 ] },
                        as: 'day',
                        in: { $dateFromParts : { 'year': 2019, 'month': 1, 'day': '$$day','hour': 0, 'minute': 0, 'second': 0,'millisecond': 0 } }
                    } }, 
                    as: 'day', 
                    cond: { $lt: ['$$day', { $dateFromParts : { 'year': 2020, 'month': 1, 'day': 1,'hour': 0, 'minute': 0, 'second': 0,'millisecond': 0 } }] }
                } },
                as: 'day',
                in: { $dateToString: { date: '$$day', format: '%Y-%m-%d' } }
            } }
        } },
        { $unwind: '$day' },
        { $lookup: {
            from: 'collection',
            let: { d: '$day' },
            pipeline: [ 
                { $match: { 
                    $expr: { $and: [ 
                        { $eq: [ '$date', '$$d' ] },
                        { $not: [ { $eq: [ '$key', null ] } ] } 
                    ] } 
                } },
                { $limit: 1 }
            ],
            as: 'docs'
        } },
        { $match: { docs: { $size: 0 } } },
        { $limit: 1 },
        { $project: { day: 1 } } 
    ]
)
```

The dates generation is wrapped in an extra $filter to work with leap years but I'd recommend to calculate number of days (367/366 - it's exclusive boundary) in the year on the application level. Then you can remove the filter and combine both `$map`s into a single one.